# .net vb or c# If (MethodReturningCollection).MethodofCollection errors when method returns nothing

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, collections

**Is there a way to do this in a single line with out calling the function twice, with out storing it as a local variable?**

Below is an example of the kind of function im working with.  Where the design of the function is to return nothing when it is empty.

**Current options I know of**

```
if not createobjectlist(0) is nothing andalso createobjectlist(0).count >5 then
    do stuff
end if
```

But that calls the function twice which I want to avoid.

```
dim tmplist as list(of object) = createobjectlist(0)

if not tmplist is nothing andalso tmplist.count > 5 then

end if
```

**Sample Function**

```
Public Function CreateObjectList(byval numtocreate as object) as list(of object)
    Dim returnlist as new list(of ojbect) 
    for i = 0 to numtocreate
        Dim testobject as ojbect = nothing
        returnlist.add(testobject)
    next

    if returnlist.count < 1 then
        returnlist = nothing
    end if

    return returnlist
End Function
```

Comment: Whats wrong with a temp variable?  Alternatively, if the method returned an empty collection, you would not have to even check for Nothing.

Comment: Why the hell was my question down voted?

Comment: No idea, not my DV.  And whoever did wont ever see your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the latest versions of C#/VB, you can use [null-conditional operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) (`?.`).

The expression `CreateObjectList()?.Count` will return `null`/`nothing` if `CreateObjectList()` returned `null`/`nothing`. The type of returned value will be `Nullable<int>`, which you can directly compare to an `int` and get the expected results (You mentioned C# in the title, so I will use C# as my VB is not very good):

```
if(CreateObjectList()?.Count > 5)
{
    // do something
}
```

By the way, your current implementation of `CreateObjectList` will never return `null` - `returnlist` is initialized in the first line to a new instance.

To make sure it always behaves this way, you can use [code contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx) and add the following:

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that was a valid command is c#.
------
That seems to be what I was looking for.    so the collection?.count basically adds in a short circuit around the getting a null error on the .count 

If you read the code at the end there is a if count < 0 set the variable = nothing.   Thats how I want it to work.